# Retrofit 2 при добавление cookie в header выходить ошибка

Tags: android, retrofit

```
public static Retrofit getClient(){
    HashSet<String> cookies = new HashSet<>();
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

            if (!response.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
                for (String header : response.headers("Set-Cookie")) {
                    cookies.add(header);
                }
            }

            return response;
        }
    });
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();

            String cookiestring = "";
            for (String cookie : cookies) {
                String[] parser = cookie.split(";");
                cookiestring = cookiestring + parser[0] + "; ";
            }
            builder.addHeader("Cookie", cookiestring);
            return chain.proceed(builder.build());
        }
    });


    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
```

response.header не пустой

```
String number =  eTxtUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = eTxtPassword.getText().toString();
            ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<AuthResponse> call =  apiInterface.auth(number,password);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<AuthResponse> call, Response<AuthResponse> response) {
                    AuthResponse authorization = response.body();
                    Headers header = response.headers();
                    Log.i("ssss","head"+ header);
                    DataAuth dataAuth = authorization.getData().get(0);
                    boolean success = dataAuth.isSuccess();
```

Вот такой ошибка выходить

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                        java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                                                                                    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.add(Collections.java:928)
                                                                                    at marketmobile.project.kz.marketmobile.rest.ApiClient.getClient(ApiClient.java:78)
                                                                                    at marketmobile.project.kz.marketmobile.fragment.LoginFragment$2.onClick(LoginFragment.java:92)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно добавляете `Interceptor`

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(new YourInterceptor())
    .build();
```

А `client.interceptors().add()` будет кидать исключение.

И еще лучше не создавать каждый раз новый OkHttpClient, а сохранить его в статическое поле и использовать повторно. Возможно без этого кукисы и не заведутся.

А еще лучше использовать готовую [библиотеку](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar), вместо изобретения велосипедов.